# How to force remote to earlier commit

Tags: git, github, git-push

I pushed a commit to a remote repo (GitHub), and submitted a pull request.

Then I push a second commit. I found out that my second commit is now listed as part of the pull request. (Not sure why...I'll figure that out later.)

How do I reset `origin master` to the previous commit? I don't want to lose the second commit locally, just remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this:

```
$ git checkout master

# remember where the master was referencing to
$ git branch previous_master

# Reset master back to previous commit
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
$ git push --force origin master

# the original commit could be checkout using:
$ git checkout previous_master
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git push -f origin master^:master
```